# Is there any way to extract data from CSS generated content using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some data from justdail.com and while doing so I realized that the phone numbers listed on the site are not as texts in the HTML document instead they are saved as content in a css class like:

`.icon-wyx:before {content: "\9d010";}`

Here the '0' at the end is a digit of the phone number is there any way for me to extract these digits from the css content using BeautifulSoup?

The html linked to the css is

```html
<span class="mobilesv icon-poh">
   ::before
</span>
```

Attaching the screenshot here:

[inspect img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcakh.png)

[inspect img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icFDx.png)

My code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= "https://www.justdial.com/Balasore/Readymade-Garment-Retailers/nct-10401947/page-1"

r = requests.get(url=url,headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)"})
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
orgs = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col-sm-5 col-xs-8 store-details sp-detail paddingR0'})

org_name = orgs[0].find('span', {'class':'lng_cont_name'}).attrs['data-cn']
print(org_name)

org_phone = orgs[0].find_all('span',{'class':'mobilesv'})
print(org_phone[0])
```

The output:

```
200
City Life
<span class="mobilesv icon-tsj"></span>
```

Here as we can see the css of the class icon-tsj is no where to be found in the parshed html but the value of it's content attribute is required to scrape the phone number. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Maybe you can get the css file that defines these classes and work with that

Comment: The CSS is in the page source (accessible via View Source, not the Chrome dev tools) on line 189. You should be able to parse it using the span class (`icon-vuk`, for example) and get the digit at the end.